# Move an element right when window width decreases using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

### Default behavior

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

When the window is resized the div remains 25% from the left edge of it's container.

[image]

Can we increase *or give the illusion of* the percentage value of the `left` property **increasing** as the window's width is decreased?

**Edit: Is this possible without using 1000 media queries or JavaScript while keeping a smooth, consistent, un-jittery transition?**

***I've actually achieved this effect with pure CSS a long time ago but forgot how it was done. My code was kind of convoluted and used a lot of percentages for widths and absolute positioning. But I know it's possible. Looking for a CSS hack at the very least.***

Comment: You need media queries to achieve that. This should help you: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @pegla Thank you but media queries won't be a smooth transition unless we have like a million lol

Comment: if you want smooth you can have transition property on css, tweak it a bit, for starters, transition: 1s all; There's always JS if you don't mind using it.

Comment: @pegla Using transitions still won't be as smooth as the default behavior in my example. It will animate only at breakpoints. I wan't a more linear transition that depends on the size of the browser window for each calculator. Exactly how default CSS works in my example but with moving right instead of left.

Comment: So you want to have for example `left: 20%` when width = 1024px and `left: 30%` when width = 768px and so on?

Comment: @MarcinSzwarc yes but it doesn't have to be precise values. Just to give the illusion that the div is travelling right as width decreases. Feel free to change the HTML markup as much as needed as well. I'm aware some parent divs and percentages might be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get something near what you're looking for by having the distance from the left being composed of negative-scalar + constant values, instead of just a positive-scalar:

```css
@keyframes changeSize {
  0%   { width: 100%; left: 0%; }
  50%  { width: 30%; left: 35%; }
  100% { width: 100%; left: 0%; }
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  left: 0%; top: 0%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000000;
  
  animation-name: changeSize;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.container > .box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  background-color: #000000;
  top: 50%; margin-top: -25px;
  left: -20%; margin-left: 150px; /* here's the negative-scalar + constant! */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

The scalar becomes more significant, percentage-wise, as the parent's size decreases.

Note that the animation is just for demonstration! :)

Comment: This is pretty great.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `calc()` function of CSS. It evaluates an expression inside.

```
div {
  left: calc(-25% + 100px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/93hLhhvp/

Answer (score 1):

To some extent it's possible: You can use the `right` property instead of `left` and a `calc` value for it that contains a percentage higher than 100%, minus a relatively large fixed value. It's some trial and error to find a setting that's appropriate for your individual situation:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(140% - 500px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Media Query in CSS

[Learn More About Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Example Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div {
    left: 50%;
  }
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
   <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See my edit. Media queries won't provide a smooth transition as it is with percentages in default CSS like in my example.

Comment: I think you need Jquery.resize() to do that.
See it here:
https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: See @Gershom Maes's answer